# Can a question be too complicated to solve by the community?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [Android TCP error failed to resolve host name from static library](https://superuser.com/questions/1141609/android-tcp-error-failed-to-resolve-host-name-from-static-library)

Can a question be too complicated for superuser ? I have posted this question few days ago and edited it couple of times. I have included all the information i could have gathered, did multiple tests and formatted the question couple of time.
I think that my question is on point and well documented, as it got around 60 views, but without any real answers.
Can a question be too hard ? Can it be something that requires special assistance that superuser cant support?

Comment: Note that a question is visible on the main page only for a very short time on SU. This does not help in attracting eyes...

Comment: I'll be honest I think its probably borderline off-topic for [su]

Answer (score 2):

This community, like most Stack Exchange sites, is full of experts on all kinds of topics. Sometimes question go unanswered for a long time for a variety of reasons. Relevantly, troubleshooting questions can have [limited information](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6837/380318), and some just get lost in the flood of new questions.

Always make sure you've included all the things you tried and what happened. Provide context for the specific task you're trying to accomplish (sometimes people can solve the problem without answering the question).

Do your best to make your question easy to read. If I was looking at a few questions I might want to investigate, I would want to go after the one I can read and understand with the least cognitive energy expended.

Probably, though, you should just wait. I see the question is attracting a few helpful comments, and I suspect you'll find a good answer soon. It's not unheard of for awesome answers to come in weeks or months later.

Comment: Might be it, i tried really hard providing all the information i could, and all of the steps i took to try to solve it, as well as reformatting couple of times in order to provide better viewing/reading experience. I guess time will tell.