# How to make question not "too broad"?

Tags: support, specific-question

Recently I posted [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1195510/wifi-has-limited-connectivity-but-works-after-disconnecting-for-a-few-minutes) that was soon closed for being "too broad", without any comments. I would really like an answer to my question, but there's not much more details I can add. Is there any way to modify my question to fit within the community guidelines?

(I realize this question itself is kind of broad, it would be funny if you also closed it without comment).

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Are diagnostics/troubleshooting issues on-topic and not too localized?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6837/380318)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have included in your question, it's not possible to provide a reasonably *definitive* answer. You're clearly in the early stages of troubleshooting a problem that could have a **broad** number of possible solutions.

In order to make your question fit the Q&A format of Super User, you must include more information. Here are some suggestions to get you started:

- Make/model of your wireless card and laptop
- Details about the wireless driver
- Output of `ipconfig /all` when you do, and do not have connectivity
- Any relevant entries from the Windows Event Logs
- Describe what happened between the last time it worked and when it stopped working

Do your best to use good formatting to make your question easier to read, and be as concise as possible with what you include to avoid going the other direction by creating a question too long to keep folks' interest.

All this said, your question by nature is a *troubleshooting* question. Such questions, even with adequate details, tend to require back-and-fourth "try this and report back" discussion, which is more suitable for a forum than Super User. So while you may get lucky if someone recognizes your problem as common, be prepared for the possibility it still cannot be answered definitely.

Comment: You should not strive to seek that one person who might have experienced the same problem, you should seek that person who can recongize your problem (once they have enough information) and how to solve it, as those are the people that are more likely to have actual permanent fixes to the problem instead of workarounds