# My post was unfairly closed

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question about my internet abnormality.

[Bad internet connections running my program but most speed test results are normal except for one](https://superuser.com/questions/1770653/bad-internet-connections-running-my-program-but-most-speed-test-results-are-norm)

I explained

- How I discovered the problem.
- How I narrow down the problem to be an internet issue, not program or
  remote server issue.
- The weird behavior when I run speed test on the internet.
- My ISP was not able to solve the problem.

But "I need to provide more details", yeah I would do that if possible, but I already gave every info I can provide.

Even if there are more info I can provide that I didn't think of. You should keep the thread open so people can ask for it.

"You are not understanding how this site operates" - direct quote from the moderator

My bad I thought this is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 6):

Well looking at it - I feel like part of the issue is there's a lot of information, but a lot of it is irrelevant.

> I tested the internet connection on the computer. Speedtest, fast.com, my ISP test site all shows the speed is normal at 290 to 320 mbps. But speedcheck shows the internet speed is 4 mbps at daytime, 2mbps at night. That is exactly what my program experienced.

Tells you that your ISP's connection to speedcheck is bad. *But* lots of ISPs host speed test servers locally, and this might be a bottleneck elsewhere.

> I contacted my ISP, they checked the status and log, they were unable to identify any problem. They say they can't do anything if it was just my own program or one speed testing site while all the others shows the speed is normal.

this is vaguely true

> I can't ping the websocket server, it didn't respond. I pinged the REST API from the same site that gives me the websocket API, it was normal.

Lots of servers turn off ping. Unless you mean something different from ping the command.

> My application is time sensitive, so I set a tolerance of 0.8 seconds. If the program didn't receive next update after 0.8 seconds, it will halt and restart after 60 seconds.

I feel like this is less of a 'speed' issue than a latency issue. And I feel like 'how do I monitor my network connection?' with respect to this is the heart of the problem. Fixing it is unfortunately out of your hands.

Its not a 'thread' though, its a question. Also, I'm taking exception to whoever said "the question will never be reopened" - they will and questions *can* be fixed. And the comments should help with that, not discourage folks.

Answer (score 5):

You might be asking the wrong question, and asking in wrong place. IMO it looks more related to software engineering (system architecture, testing, reliability, benchmarking, etc.) than about using computers as is defined in the https://superuser.com/help/on-topic.

I suggest you to ask for site recommendation in https://meta.stackexchange.com as the question might have to be splitted and some parts might be on topic in different sites and others might not be any site on the Stack Exchange network for them.

---

I didn't participate in the closing of the question but it looks that the current question's version is not a good fit for this site and the "troubleshooting model" isn't working.

In first place that the question be "closed" it only says that the question is not a good fit at certain moment. You could still get help, and the question could be reopend and get an answer.

In general the model of the system that power Super User is not good for handling questions that require a lot of back and forth but still some Super User community members try to help and at the same time the can be enforcing the site guidelines, in other words, voting to close among any other moderation actions doesn't mean that they are not willing to help.

If the workings of this site doesn't work for you, first you should review is you know enough about them.

Related

- [Are diagnostics/troubleshooting issues on-topic and not too localized?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6837/152004)
- [2023 stand about "troubleshooting"](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14888/152004)

Answer (score 4):

### Your question simply doesn’t provide enough details and you have not even asked for clarification on what those new details might be.

#### This answer on meta is a clarification and response to your question here, but if you scroll down you can see what I believe are very valid points that explain what kind of details *might* rescue your question from closure and make it a good re-open candidate.

I have said this previously in comments I have now deleted on [the original](https://superuser.com/q/1770653/167207) post to cool things down, but sadly your post here shows you are simply not “getting it.”

The title of this meta question is not a valid question in my mind:

> “My post was unfairly closed”

Unfairly closed by whose criteria and to whose benefit? All I can read in this question is “Something happened and I don’t like it.” A better question for meta would have been:

> “I don’t understand why my question was closed. Can I get some guidance on what happened?”

Being personally slighted is not a valid reason to wanting your question to be reopened. The stated close reason is as follows:

> “Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.”

But instead of asking for what details are needed, you claim here:

> “But "I need to provide more details", yeah I would do that if possible, but I already gave every info I can provide.”

Excuse me? You have not provided any useful details, but I will explain later. For now you stated this:

> “"You are not understanding how this site operates" - direct quote from the moderator”

Yes, that was my quote. But I am not a moderator at all; I am a regular user here. What I did was vote on to close the question. Most any user with a basic level of reputation can vote to close a question. And in this case two users (me and [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)) as well as one moderator ([DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)) voted to close the question).

And when I [pointed this out to you in the comments](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14915/my-post-was-unfairly-closed?noredirect=1#comment43765_14915) on this meta post [your response was](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14915/my-post-was-unfairly-closed?noredirect=1#comment43766_14915):

> “@Giacomo1968 A person who can close other people's post by force is a moderator, no matter how you want to call it.”

Excuse me? I am ONE lone user here. The question *was not* closed because of my ONE close vote; it took one other person and a moderator to come to a consensus and then the question was closed. You might be a relatively new user to SuperUser but you clearly are not a new user of Stack Exchange sites at all. But anyway, [here is a guide that explains how moderation on Super User works](https://superuser.com/help/site-moderators).

That said, closed posts can be reopened. [This guide](https://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions) explains how to reopen a question on SuperUser.

---

That said…

### What can you do to reopen your question?

You said this before:

> “…yeah I would do that if possible, but I already gave every info I can provide.”

Again, you provided *no useful info at all*. You simply posted a lot of details that primarily abstractly explain what you did but no details others could use to help you. So here is a list of what I believe you can add to your question that would make it a viable candidate for reopening:

- What is the exact make and model of your Windows machine?
- What version of Windows is being used?
- What is the exact make and model of the modem and/or router you use to connect to your ISP?
- Is this a hard-wired Ethernet connection between your PC and the Internet modem/router? Or is it a Wi-Fi connection?
- Internet speed is always an unreliable metric when measuring performance like this. So your writing about various consumer spend benchmark results is meaningless. A better test would be to use traceroute to see if there are any devices between you, your ISP and the data source that might choke.
- Was there a Windows or Python update that might have caused a hiccup?

Now, that is all of the info that might be useful to help others debug but here are the factors that I think make this question unanswerable.

- **Download Speeds Rule Home ISP Connections**: Home ISP connections are always optimized for end-user download speeds; not incoming data connection speeds. This has always been the case but is even more of the case nowadays where digital streaming is a thing.
- **Consumer Level Accounts Don’t Are Not High Quality**: Even if you use Tracroute and find a device that chokes and seems to be unreliable. An ISP will only report back performance benchmarks and reliability based on their own internal requirements to maintain service for end users. Your issue with a process failing in the middle of the night will not be considered an issue. And past that, if the issue is some middle-device like a switch or a router at the ISP, they are not going to make it easy for you to report it since a small blip in the middle of the night would not really be considered an “outage” by most ISP standards.
- **ISPs Will Only Truly Address Issues Like This for Business Level Accounts**: If your account was a business account with 24/7 reliability, what I just wrote would not apply since business accounts guarantee higher levels of stability. A basic consumer account — which I think is what you have — would never garner any attention.

And when all is said and done, I do not think your original question has enough details to warrant a reopening because even if you added these details ISP issues like this are so unique and idiosyncratic that nobody could ever really help you here.

This is why I suggested in now deleted comments, and will again suggest it here, that [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com) is the better kind of place for this kind of troubleshooting question. In fact if you can find a Reddit or sub-Reddit that is focused on ISP issues in your area, that would be best. [DSL Reports](http://www.dslreports.com) might be another place to present your question and your issues.

---

#### Postscript to this…

The postscript to this is a comment to [RockPaperLz](https://meta.superuser.com/users/380110/rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket) who [commented as follows](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14915/my-post-was-unfairly-closed?noredirect=1#comment43776_14915); bold emphasis is mine. This postscript should be useful to the original poster:

> “I think perhaps it may be time for you to take a relaxing break. You come across as angry and short-tempered. The OP might not be handling things as you wish, or ideally, but in my opinion, you are only adding fuel to the fire, and not handling things in a calm and kind manner. **Perhaps step away for a while and enjoy the many beautiful things life has to offer? May you find peace and calmness.**”

When you (RockPaperLz) says, “I think perhaps it may be time for you to take a relaxing break.” Okay, fair enough. But when you say the final sentence “Perhaps step away for a while and enjoy the many beautiful things life has to offer? May you find peace and calmness.” This is just pandering and insulting nonsense.

Isn’t you saying this the equivalent of telling anyone anywhere with any knowledge to “[Get a life!](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xmagzq)” How dare you tell anyone to “…enjoy the many beautiful things life has to offer?” when you are basically telling them to shut up?

How dare you or anyone dare to project your impressions of motivation around posts instead of just leaving your comment as “I think perhaps it may be time for you to take a relaxing break.”

Personally, I have gotten a bit sick and tired of the politics of Stack Exchange sites. Somehow a small army of people come here and work to provide content for free but we are somehow treated like servants. I will gladly help anyone who can help themselves. In fact that is one of the reasons I started spending more and more online time on Super User.

But recently, thanks to a few incidents (not just on Super User) I have been questioning why I am doing this. I mean at the end of the day my work provides content that then allows the owners of Stack Exchange to profit from my work. And why should I deal with this headache?

Moderators and others can see that my interactions as of late have mainly been to edit posts to improve them followed by flags and comments. I haven’t been posting as many answers as I used to related to my thoughts above. But this incident with [this specific post here](https://superuser.com/q/1770653/167207) makes me question my work here. Consider it a [straw that broke the camel’s back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_that_broke_the_camel%27s_back) moment, but why am I wasting my time helping so many people who barely can help themselves for free? To my knowledge, the bulk of the posts here are not life and death situations. Sure, sometimes things are frustrating but why should I — or anyone — spend so much time effectively doing work for no pay, no compensation and the reward of being chastised and perhaps (maybe) some meager reward of rep.

So when you, RockPaperLz, states “Perhaps step away for a while and enjoy the many beautiful things life has to offer?” all I have to think is during my daily life where real things happen I never get pandered like this. So why am I giving so much to a community that gives me so little in return?

Sure, I use SE sites to solve problems I deal with in my day job and personal tech life at times. But past that, I think I need to step aside and just consume advice. I mean there are more “beautiful things life has to offer” than being insulted and degraded for doing work for free, right?

#### Anyway, if Jeffrey Chen can edit their question to add more real details as outline, I will gladly vote to re-open it. Past that, I’m done! Life is too short and there are indeed better things to do.